# add data to particular file by using outputstream

Tags: java, io, fileoutputstream

```
String data="this we want append in that file";
byte[] getbyte = data.getBytes();
outputstream.write(getbyte);
outputstream.flush();
```

by using these code i m trying to write data in particlar file but data is not get added it that file

Comment: How do you create `outputstream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import java.io.*;

public class WriteFileExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String strFilePath = "d:/FileIO.txt";

 try
 {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
  String strContent = "Write File using Java FileOutputStream example !";

  /*
   * To write byte array to a file, use
   * void write(byte[] bArray) method of Java FileOutputStream class.
   *
   * This method writes given byte array to a file.
   */

   fos.write(strContent.getBytes());

  /*
   * Close FileOutputStream using,
   * void close() method of Java FileOutputStream class.
   *
   */

   fos.close();

 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
 {
  System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex);
 }
 catch(IOException ioe)
 {
  System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
 }
```

}
  }

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to save the bytes of the string, not the serialized string object.

Comment: Thanx pravin but by these using these method i am not able  to get location of that file I palced that file in same package

Comment: HI Jeremy  in above code i am converting that sting into array of byte  and then writing that string in particular file what did u mean exactly